Strapi v5 increments ID non-sequentially Data Not Found
Strapi v5 increments ID non-sequentially Data Not Found
In strapi displays:

Mysql displays:

When i try it in postman with
Url: http://localhost:1337/api/cates/3
Result:
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundErro]",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": 1
    }
}

In Strapi v4 i didn't have this issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your snapshots says, the database is making duplicate entries. Try a new database and lookup in the terminal logs if it hits multiple queries.

use documentId, id does not work in v5

In Strapi v5; there two new notions that you need to have clear understanding of for your daily CRUD operations. Here is what you have to consider:

First we have the draft/published entries, just like for locales, they have different ids but a same documentId.
Second, always use use the new documentId attribute to read, search, update or delete single elements otherwise you will be getting 404 responses.

Notice: As for v5.2.0, user-permissions pluging still working with id attribute for CRUD operations soespectially for this plugin, use id instead of documentId
